# What do you call it when a company is sold for one dollar/euro etc.?

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose, there's a company with huge debts and it's sold for one dollar to a new owner. What do you call this amount of money (not necessarily one dollar)? A symbolic sum? A token sum?

Comment: It could be described as any number of things, depending on context and tone:  *nominal*, *de minimis*, *trivial*, etc. Are you looking for a term from the financial world? Is there a term for this in your native language that would lead you to believe one should exist in English?

Comment: @choster We would say 'a symbolic sum'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is referred to as a **nominal** (or **token**) **consideration** or [**peppercorn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppercorn_(legal)) ("a very small cash payment...used to satisfy the requirements for the creation of a legal contract"). See [here](https://scholarship.law.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2867&context=wmlr), for example, for its use in context.

Answer (score 1):

Legally, what it's called is consideration.

In normal discussions, I've always heard it stated as "one dollar."  It is indeed a token sum, but it is possible to have token sums that are not a dollar.